# Get-AzVMImage doesnt output PSVirtualMachineImageDetail

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

Im trying to fetch the detailed information from a azure VM Image but the information doesnt seem to be there.

```
$location = "swedencentral"
$publisher = "MicrosoftSQLServer" 

#Get all offers for selected publisher
$Alloffers = @(Get-AzVMImageOffer -Location $location -PublisherName $publisher | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Offer)

#Get all images for all skus of all ofers for the selected publisher
foreach ($Offer in $Alloffers) {
    $Allskus = (Get-AzVMImageSku -Location $location -PublisherName $publisher -Offer $offer | Select-Object  -ExpandProperty Skus)
    
    foreach ($sku in $Allskus) {
        $images += @(Get-AzVMImage -Location $location -PublisherName $publisher -Offer $offer -Skus $sku -Version latest)
     }
}

$images
```

According to documentation Get-AzVMImage should output PSVirtualMachineImage and PSVirtualMachineImageDetail but the result suggest that only PSVirtualMachineImage  is outputed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azvmimage?view=azps-11.1.0

Im I missing something or how can I with PowerShell get the detailed information from an Azure VM Image, specifically I want the Name and the OSDiskImage information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `-Version latest`, I notice that only partial details are returned for the image.

When using a specific version Id, more details are returned. Here is example output:

```
$temp = Get-AzVMImage -Location $location -PublisherName $publisher -Offer $offer -Skus $sku -Version latest
$imageFullDetails = Get-AzVMImage -Location $location -PublisherName $publisher -Offer $offer -Skus $sku -Version $temp.Version
```

Full output:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $temp = Get-AzVMImage -Location $location -PublisherName $publisher -Offer $offer -Skus $sku -Version latest
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $temp

Version           Skus               Offer         PublisherName          Location  Id
-------           ----               -----         -------------          --------  --
9600.21620.231004 2012-R2-Datacenter windowsserver MicrosoftWindowsServer centralus /Subscriptions/b54f6425-8460-401d-bbd4-0e6ff231ed16/Providers/Microsoft.Compute/Locations/centralus/Publishers/MicrosoftWindowsServer/ArtifactTypes/VMImage/Offers/windowsserver/Skus/2012-R2-Data...


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $imageFullDetails = Get-AzVMImage -Location $location -PublisherName $publisher -Offer $offer -Skus $sku -Version $temp.Version
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $imageFullDetails


Id                     : /Subscriptions/b54f6425-8460-401d-bbd4-0e6ff231ed16/Providers/Microsoft.Compute/Locations/centralus/Publishers/MicrosoftWindowsServer/ArtifactTypes/VMImage/Offers/windowsserver/Skus/2012-R2-Datacenter/Versions/9600.21620.231004
Location               : centralus
PublisherName          : MicrosoftWindowsServer
Offer                  : windowsserver
Skus                   : 2012-R2-Datacenter
Version                : 9600.21620.231004
FilterExpression       :
Name                   : 9600.21620.231004
HyperVGeneration       : V1
OSDiskImage            : {
                           "operatingSystem": "Windows"
                         }
PurchasePlan           : null
DataDiskImages         : []
ImageDeprecationStatus : {
                           "imageState": "Active",
                           "scheduledDeprecationTime": null,
                           "alternativeOption": null
                         }



PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Comment: Great catch, it will be slower to iterate through all of them and fetch them using the specific image details but at least it will work. Thanks